# Using emacs for large multi-file JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, c++, emacs, project-management, webgl

I am looking to port a game from C++ to JavaScript/WebGL, and I want to use emacs.

I will probably use js2-mode for code editing, but what would be a good way to manage the multi-file multi-class project?

I am using Ubuntu if it matters.

Comment: what are you talking about?  i.e. what do you mean by "manage"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an explicit project manager exists for JS. [Here's](http://blog.deadpansincerity.com/2011/05/setting-up-emacs-as-a-javascript-editing-environment-for-fun-and-profit/) a pretty good step-by-step for setting up Emacs as a node environment though.